# react native environment variables .env return undefined

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, expo, dotenv

I am currently using dotenv but there seems to be some caching issue with the @env. So wanted to try using process.env but it returns undefined. I am using expo, dotenv and webpack.
On app.js  process.env.REACT_APP_KEY returns undefined, already restarted server, terminal and even my PC.

.env

```
REACT_APP_KEY=aaddddawrfffvvvvssaa
REACT_APP_KEY = aaddddawrfffvvvvssa
```

**Webpack config**

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);
const path = require('path')

config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map(rule => {
    if (rule.oneOf) {
        let hasModified = false;

        const newRule = {
            ...rule,
            oneOf: rule.oneOf.map(oneOfRule => {
                if (oneOfRule.use && oneOfRule.use.loader && oneOfRule.use.loader.includes('babel-loader')) {
                    oneOfRule.include = [
                        path.resolve('.'),
                        path.resolve('node_modules/@ui-kitten/components'),
                    ]
                }
                if (oneOfRule.test && oneOfRule.test.toString().includes('svg')) {
                    hasModified = true;
                    const test = oneOfRule.test.toString().replace('|svg', '');
                    return {...oneOfRule, test: new RegExp(test)};
                } else {
                    return oneOfRule;
                }
            })
        };

        // Add new rule to use svgr
        // Place at the beginning so that the default loader doesn't catch it
        if (hasModified) {
            newRule.oneOf.unshift({
                test: /\.svg$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: '@svgr/webpack',
                    }
                ]
            });
        }

        return newRule;
    } else {
        return rule;
    }
});

return config;
};
```

babel config

```
    module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      ['module:react-native-dotenv', {
        'moduleName': '@env',
        'path': '.env',
        "blocklist": null,
        "allowlist": null,
        "safe": true,
        "allowUndefined": false,
      }]
    ],
  };
};
```

If it matters (for dotenv)

```
declare module '@env' {
  export const API_ENDPOINT: string;
}
```

Also tried process.env.NODE_ENV (which is working and prints "development" as output). Only process.env.VARIABLE_NAME is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintainer here! `process.env` support in `react-native-dotenv` was just added this month https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/issues/187

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get work with Expo v48.0.19. Receiving Unable to resolve "@env". This issue on GitHub is still unresolved.

Comment: Hi @lortschi please open a new ticket with reproduction and I'm happy to help